# How to get value in percentage (%) or pixel (px) after doing some maths? | Lesscss

Tags: less

I've a little and simple question regarding Lesscss. How I can get calculated value in percentage or pixel in Lesscss. Like, I have this : **`((1 / 1) * 1) = 1`**. I know the answer is `1`, but I want this `"1"` to be in percentage or pixel like this: `"1%"` or `"1px"`.

I just need to insert or put `percentage (%)` or `pixel (px)` sign in the calculated value.

I'd appreciate the help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use:

```
unit(@yourvalue,px)
```

or

```
unit(@yourvalue,~"%")
```

[read more here](http://lesscss.org/#reference)

**Additional note:**
by default the first occurring unit in the calculation will be assigned to the result. For example `unit((1 / 2 * 3),px);` and `(1px / 2% * 3rem)` will both return `1.5px`.

Comment: Using `unit(@yourvalue,%)` for a percentage causes a syntax error.

Comment: @MatthewBaker Thanks. I changed it to `unit(@yourvalue,~"%")`, now it should be definitely working. It also works like that: `@a: 50; @b: %; unit(@a, @b);`. However, depending on your operation/value you should also consider using the `percentage()` function.

Comment: Note that `unit(@value, %)` is enough, `~"%"` is no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. What's required is to simply multiply (1%) or (1px) with the calculated value.

For Percentage: `((1 / 1) * 1) * 1%` = `1%`
For Pixel: `((1 / 1) * 1) * 1px` = `1px`

Good Luck! (Y).

Comment: have you even looked at my answer? your solution works only if non of the values in the calculation already have any units assigned ... otherwise the one occurring first will be displayed in the result. To override this default or to remove units I would use the `unit()` function. **Good luck to you too!** ^_^